# Why am I only getting an Unhandled Exception Type error only when using List.forEach?

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, foreach, throw

I have some method that throws an exception:

```java
public void myMethod(MyBean bean) throws SomeException {
    ...
}
```

And another method is calling this method like this with no errors/warnings from Eclipse:

```java
public void processBeanList(List<MyBean> myBeanList) {
    for (int i = 0; i < myBeanList.size(); i++) {
        MyBean myBean = myBeanList.get(i);
        myMethod(myBean);
    }
}
```

However if I change the implementation of this `processBeanList` to the following, I get an "Unhandled exception type SomeException" error:

```java
public void processBeanList(List<MyBean> myBeanList) {
    myBeanList.forEach(myBean -> {
        myMethod(myBean); // Eclipse underlines this, mentions error
    });
}
```

I realize that if the method throws the Exception then it should be handled or re-thrown, but is there something different between these two implementations that I'm missing, which would lead Eclipse to show the error in once case and not the other? Or is this just something that Eclipse, for whatever reason, is picking up in the second instance, but not in the first when it should be picked up in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the parameter of [forEach(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) is a [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html).

```
myBean -> {
  myMethod(myBean);
}
```

The above is an implementation of consumer as lambda function.

`Consumer.accept()` does not throw exceptions, so you have to handle it in some way - possibly catch and rethrow as unchecked exception.

Comment: So `myMethod` is called by the lambda function Consumer, whose `accept` method doesn't throw exceptions, ok. But `myMethod` is also called by `processBeanList` which doesn't throw the exception either. Why no error in that case?

Comment: Are we talking about compiler error reporting, or squiggly red underlines in an IDE?  It's not impossible that the IDE doesn't diagnose all illegal code.

Comment: @devjoco Is `SomeException` checked or unchecked? Looks like bug in eclipse, but i would check with the compiler just to be sure. If it's checked exception you should get errors in both cases, if it's unchecked, both should compile successfully.

Comment: Ah I just figured it out. `SomeException` is a custom exception that extends `SQLException`. I omitted this from my question, thinking it irrelevant, but the `processBeanList` method actually throws `SQLException`, which would cover its subclass `SomeException` as well. Of course, this `Consumer.accept()` does not throw anything, hence the error.